# Cannot install inside docker container

Tags: node.js, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I'm quite new at docker, but I'm facing a problem I have no idea how to solve it.

I have a jenkins (docker) image running and everything was fine. A few days ago I created a job so I can run my nodejs tests every time a pull request is made. one of the job's build steps is to run `npm install`. And the job is constantly failing with this error:

`tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory`

So, I know that I have to install `bzip2` inside the jenkins container, but how do I do that? I've already tried to run `docker run jenkins bash -c "sudo apt-get bzip2"` but I got: `bash: sudo: command not found`.

With that said, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this lies inside the philosophy of dcoker containers. Docker containers are/should be immutable. So, this is what you can try to fix this issue.

1. Treat your base image i.e, jenkins as starting point.
2. login to this base image and install bzip2.
3. commit these changes and this should result in a new image.
4. Now use above image from step 3 to install any other package like npm.
5. Now commit above image.

Note: To execute commands in much controlled way, I always prefer to use something like this;

docker exec -it jenkins bash

In nutshell, answer to both of your current issues lie in the fact that images are immutable so to make any change that will get propagated is to commit them and use newly created image to make further changes. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of issues here, but the biggest one is that you need to build your images with the tools you need rather than installing inside of a running container. As techtrainer mentions, images are immutable and don't change (at least from your running container), and containers are disposable (so any changes you make inside them are lost when you restart them unless your data is stored outside the container in a volume).

I do disagree with techtrainer on making your changes in a container and committing them to an image with `docker commit`. This will work, but it's the hand built method that is very error prone and not easily reproduced. Instead, you should leverage a Dockerfile and use `docker build`. You can either modify the jenkins image you're using by directly modifying it's Dockerfile, or you can create a child image that is `FROM jenkins:latest`.

When modifying this image, the Jenkins image is configured to run as the user "jenkins", so you'll need to switch to root to perform your application installs. The "sudo" app is not included in most images, but external to the container, you can run docker commands as any user. From the cli, that's as easy as `docker run -u root ...`. And inside your Dockerfile, you just need a `USER root` at the top and then `USER jenkins` at the end.

One last piece of advice is to not run your builds directly on the jenkins container, but rather run agents with your needed build tools that you can upgrade independently from the jenkins container. It's much more flexible, allows you to have multiple environments with only the tools needed for that environment, and if you scale this up, you can use a plugin to spin up agents on demand so you could have hundreds of possible agents to use and only be running a handful of them concurrently.